# What terms would describe the art style of Railbound?

Tags: terminology, art

I am researching different art styles to find one fit for my game, and want to look for more games in the style of Railbound, but not sure how best to describe its art style - the color palette choice, how objects are shaped and shaded, etc.
Adding a screenshot from the game.

[image: Railbound]

Comment: I would say this is one of the cartoon looks, top-down isometric 2d cartoon look.

Comment: https://twitter.com/AfterburnGames/status/1593258212433702912?lang=en